Spring cloud gateway gives me "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" when i perform POST
i only have 2 dependecy in gateway server, ouath2 client and spring-cloud-starter-gateway.
here is the code i have in gateway server

  @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder ) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("resource-server1", r -> r
                        .path("/private")
                        .filters(GatewayFilterSpec::tokenRelay)
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080/private"))
                
                .route("userPools", r -> r
                        .path("/list-user-pools")
                        .filters(GatewayFilterSpec::tokenRelay)
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080/list-user-pools"))

exc...

 .build();


everything is fine when i perform get request, api gateway points me to aws cognito to login, it then uses the token to access the resource server 8080. the problem only happens when i send post, i get this error "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" in postman and browser, no logs in the gateway server. any one know why the api gateway wont allow me to send post

i did add spring security config and disabled csrf just to test it out, after i added the code
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())

                .build();
    }
}


the application wont even start and i get the error.
here is logs image when i start the program after i added securityconfig

csrf is not something i want to disable, becuase i heard it is good to have it enabled.
i know the problem is only the api gateway becuase i tested sending post request to resource server with token in the header and it works, the big problem is gateway wont let me send post,

Your server uses reactive, but your Spring Security conifguration is for servlets. You have to use a reactive Spring Security configuration.

i disabled the csrf and post request works, but disabling the csrf is not what i wanted
"@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
return http
.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)"
is there a way or configuration to let the gateway know i want to allow POST

Do not post code in comments, use the [edit] link and change your question.
